# Objective-c Novice needs help - UIView controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i have created some uiviews (view1 and view2) and in my MainView implementation file i set the text of labels for labels in those views, but they are not showing. Do i need to reference that particular uiview somehow, or how do i do this?

Here is what i have got, but at the minute no text is showing on my labels or buttons. Here is my code:

```
-(IBAction)lvl1Next{

    switch (questionNum)
    {
        case 0:
            [lvl1ButtonA setTitle:@"A: 372" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [lvl1ButtonB setTitle:@"B: 376" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [lvl1ButtonC setTitle:@"C: 374" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
            [lvl1LabelQuestion setText:(@"1. 139 + 235 =")];
            answer=@"3";
            break;
        case 1:
                 .....
```

Anyone know why my labels are not showing? When i try:

```
[view2.lvl1ButtonA setTitle:@"A: 372" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

I get an error: "request for member not a structure or union".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You reference UILabels and UIButtons through outlets, or programmatically by adding them to UIViews. You've produced no evidence of having done either of those two things in the question above.

The error on this line of code, indicates that you are not familiar with adding UIButtons to UIViews, or referencing UIButtons once the are added to views.

```
[view2.lvl1ButtonA setTitle:@"A: 372" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
```

You can't access a UIButton this way. To reference an object (button or label) added using IB. You would specify an IBOutlet in your .h file like so:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *lvl1ButtonA;
```

I'll let you search StackOverflow for the code to add a UIButton or UILabel to a view via code.

Anyhoo, to answer your question, check (or search) how to add UIButton or UILabel to UIView via code and via Interface Builder.

Comment: In my mainview header class i have referenced all these buttons and views: @interface MainView : UIView {
    IBOutlet UIView *view1;
    IBOutlet UIView *view2;
    IBOutlet UIView *view3;
    ...
    IBOutlet UIButton *lvl1ButtonNext; but they label texts are not showing when i go click the button to go into level 1.

Comment: I found that if i put that code in the button to go to view 1 then it shows works. Dont think this is proper coding though.

Comment: If you want help, Edit your question and post all of the relevant code.